Excel VBA Trend Function Error "Type Mismatch" In formula
I am trying to implement a formula including a forecasted number using the trend function. The trend function itself works fine, however, once I paste it into the formula (e.g. sth as simple as adding +1), I get the error message "Type mismatch".
Sub Test()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")

Set ys= Range("Output!P6:P7")
Set xs= Range("Output!S6:S7")
Set x= Range("Output!T6")

Range("P" & 8) = Application.Trend(ys, xs, x, True) + 1

End With

End Sub

I found a workaround where I hardcode the value generated by the trend function into another cell, then draw the value from that cell using Range().Value. However, I would like to prevent having to use helper cells, so I was wondering if anyone could explain as to why the code isn't working in the first place. Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Side note, unrelated to the error. You need a . in front of every instance of Range, and then "Output!P6:P7" --> "P6:P7" and so on. Your With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output") is doing absolutely nothing otherwise.

Hi BigBen, thanks for your input. I've simplified my code from a much longer piece of code, where I'm switching between different worksheets, but of course you're absolutely right.

Application.Trend returns an array, to which you can't directly + 1. You can determine this using VarType.

As @BigBen wrote, the result of the Trend function is an array, so you should read its first (and only) element.
Sub Test()
    Dim ys As Range, xs As Range, x As Range
    Set ys = Range("P6:P7")
    Set xs = Range("S6:S7")
    Set x = Range("T6")
    Range("P" & 8).Value = Application.Trend(ys, xs, x, True)(1) + 1
End Sub

